# how to use U256 in near smart contract in rust language

Tags: rust, blockchain, nearprotocol

I am trying to use U256 in rust smart contract for near protocol with a library called `ethnum`. But it always give errors like:

```
the trait `JsonSchema` is not implemented for `U256`
 │     |
 │     = help: the following other types implement trait `JsonSchema`:
 │               &'a T
 │               &'a mut T
 │               ()
 │               (T0, T1)
 │               (T0, T1, T2)
 │               (T0, T1, T2, T3)
 │               (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
 │               (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
```

I expect a smart contract which use U256 library to sum, change, multiply etc. so that it can be used for other smart contracts too in NEAR protocol's rust smart contract.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised, because [`ethnum::U256`](https://docs.rs/ethnum/latest/ethnum/struct.U256.html) does not implement the [`schemars::JsonSchema`](https://docs.rs/schemars/latest/schemars/trait.JsonSchema.html) trait. Unfortunately you can't implement `JsonSchema` on `U256` yourself (trying to implement a foreign trait on foreign type would raise another error, namely [`E0117`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0117.html)). But you can create a wrapper type around `U256` (this is called the [newtype](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html) pattern) and implement `JsonSchema` for it:

```
/*
[dependencies]
ethnum = { version = "1", features = ["serde"] }
schemars = "0.8"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
*/
use ethnum::U256 as _U256;
use schemars::{
    gen::SchemaGenerator,
    schema::{InstanceType, Schema, SchemaObject},
    schema_for, JsonSchema,
};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct U256(_U256);

impl JsonSchema for U256 {
    fn schema_name() -> String {
        "u256".to_owned()
    }

    fn json_schema(_: &mut SchemaGenerator) -> Schema {
        let mut schema = SchemaObject {
            instance_type: Some(InstanceType::Integer.into()),
            format: Some(Self::schema_name()),
            ..Default::default()
        };
        schema.number().minimum = Some(0.0);
        schema.into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u256_schema = schema_for!(U256);
    println!("{u256_schema:?}");
}
```

[Rustexplorer.](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aethnum%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%221%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22serde%22%5D%20%7D%0Aschemars%20%3D%20%220.8%22%0Aserde%20%3D%20%7B%20version%20%3D%20%221%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22derive%22%5D%20%7D%0A*%2F%0Ause%20ethnum%3A%3AU256%20as%20_U256%3B%0Ause%20schemars%3A%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20gen%3A%3ASchemaGenerator%2C%0A%20%20%20%20schema%3A%3A%7BInstanceType%2C%20Schema%2C%20SchemaObject%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20schema_for%2C%20JsonSchema%2C%0A%7D%3B%0Ause%20serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%2C%20Deserialize%7D%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Serialize%2C%20Deserialize)%5D%0Astruct%20U256(_U256)%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20JsonSchema%20for%20U256%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20schema_name()%20-%3E%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22u256%22.to_owned()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20json_schema(_%3A%20%26mut%20SchemaGenerator)%20-%3E%20Schema%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20schema%20%3D%20SchemaObject%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20instance_type%3A%20Some(InstanceType%3A%3AInteger.into())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format%3A%20Some(Self%3A%3Aschema_name())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..Default%3A%3Adefault()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema.number().minimum%20%3D%20Some(0.0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema.into()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20u256_schema%20%3D%20schema_for!(U256)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bu256_schema%3A%3F%7D%22)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: when i run the same code at https://remix.ethereum.org/, it also give similer error:  the trait bound `ethnum::U256: Serialize` is not satisfied

Comment: Have you imported `ethnum` like I did? With the `serde` feature? I.e. is this how you import it in your `Cargo.toml` file: `ethnum = { version = "1", features = ["serde"] }`